# Vue: global v-directive working in one component but not another

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I declared the following in `main.js`

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        el.checkOutside = (event) => {
            if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
            }
        };

        document.body.addEventListener('click', el.checkOutside);
    },
    unbind: function (el) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.checkOutside)
    }
});
```

In my `Properties.vue` file I use the following which works perfectly:

```
<button id="roomBGColor" class="changeBgBtn" ref="bgColorBtn" :title="$t('room_editor.tt_room_background')"
    @click="$nextTick(()=>{changeingBG = !changeingBG})"
    v-click-outside="closeRoomBGColorEditor">
        <!--some simple html forms-->
</button>
```

Then in another component `LogoMenu.vue` I use it like so:

```
<button class="fileMenu" @click="(event)=>{event.stopPropagation(); fileVisible = !fileVisible}"
    v-click-outside="closeMenu">
    ED
    <div ref="dropDown" class="dropDown" v-show="fileVisible">
        <button
            v-for="choice in choices"
            :key="choice.id"
            @click="choice.method()"
            class="choice">{{choice.text}}</button>
    </div>
</button>
```

Except this time it doesn't work and throws a `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: click-outside` error. Neither `Properties.vue` or `LogoMenu.vue` are using any imports like `import vue` or anything like that. I really can't figure out the difference why it's working in one file but not the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on CodeSandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dew-smd7u?file=/src/App.vue Although I couldn't seem to get it to work at all this time

Answer (score 3):

I sort of figured it out. To get it working I had to make sure that the directive was declared *before* the `new Vue` part in `main.js`

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {/* code */});

new Vue({
    /* code */
})
```

I still don't understand why it worked in one component and not the other, but I'm unable to reproduce that scenario from scratch so I feel it will always remain a mystery (if you know the real answer though don't hesitate to leave it down below).